# FCM Error: java.net.UnknownHostException: fcm.googleapis.com

Tags: firebase, google-api, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-api-java-client

I am making a `POST` call to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` to send push notification to a device using FCM (Firebase cloud Messaging).

But I am getting an error that says

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: fcm.googleapis.com.
```

Could you help find out the cause?

Comment: Error I am getting in tomcat:

Comment: This error in your DNS system. Not from FCM.
Try changing the DNS. You can try with 8.8.8.8

Comment: I get this error when my requests takes too long time to respond. Basically internet connectivity/DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its DNS error. Proxy were blocking call to google apis.